# Filter Matrix by some column value

Tags: matlab, matrix

Consider I have this Matrix:

```
   02, 04, 06, 08, 10, 2
   07, 14, 21, 28, 35, 2
   11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 0
   15, 14, 21, 28, 35, 2
```

I would like to have the same matrix but with only rows with last `column = 2`. So I want this Matrix:

```
   02, 04, 06, 08, 10, 2
   07, 14, 21, 28, 35, 2
   15, 14, 21, 28, 35, 2
```

I could parse all matrix, but is there any other way?

### Edit

To be more precise I have a cell array with strings:

```
   02, 04, Some String, 08, 10, 2
   07, 14, Some String1, 28, 35, 2
   11, 22, Some String1, 44, 55, 0
   15, 14, Some String, 28, 35, 2
```

Comment: Slight generalization of this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299370/filter-matrix-by-multiple-column-values-w-o-loops-matlab

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just use logical indexing on the rows of your matrix:

```
row_idx = (A(:, end) == 2);
```

Now `row_idx` contains a logical array of `1`s and `0`s, with `1`s where the last element of the row equals 2.

Now filter these rows with:

```
A_filtered = A(row_idx, :);
```

All these steps are usually performed in a one-liner:

```
A_filtered = A(A(:, end) == 2, :);
```

Comment: What if I want to filter like that by values in multiple columns?

Comment: @Pransas You can use the filtering mentioned above for more than one dimension (instead of a colon (`:`))