# Filter matrix by multiple column values w/o loops (Matlab)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Say I have the following:

- Data matrix **M** (*m*-by-*n*);
- Matching row **V** (*1*-by-*n*);
- Matching positions **I** (*1*-by-*n* logical);

I want to filter all rows of **M** that have the same values as **V** at the matching positions **I**. I believe that Matlab indexing if powerful enough to do that without loops. But how?

---

Current solution: run though all the columns and update the filtered row positions **F** (*m*-by-*1* logical).

```
F = true(m,1);
for k = 1:n;
    if I(k);
        F = F & (M(:,k)==V(k));
    end;
end;
M = M(F,:);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
result = M(all(bsxfun(@eq, M(:,I), V(I)), 2), :);
```

**How it works**

Each row of `M(:,I)` is compared element-wise with the row vector `V(I)` using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). Rows for which [`all`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) columns match are selected. The resulting logical vector is used to index the rows of `M`.

**Example**

```
M = [ 8     3     6     9
      5     4     9     8
      8     9     6     9 ];
I = [ true false true true ];
V = [ 8    1     6     9 ];

>> result = M(all(bsxfun(@eq, M(:,I), V(I)), 2), :)
result =
     8     3     6     9
     8     9     6     9
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice and concise answer!