# How do you plot a graph evolving over time?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have data about a network showing edges and nodes such as:

```
    edges = ...
    [5  7   1;
    5   7   2;
    5   11  2;
    5   7   3;
    5   11  3;
    5   16  3;
    5   7   4;
    5   11  4;
    5   16  4;
    5   21  4];
```

I'd like to obtain multiple different plots based on how those edges evolve because those edges are the result of a long observation (e.g. one year).

Each edge occurs at a different moment and therefore, I'd like to get those six different plots separately.

Suppose, the first month I see these edges:

```
    edges = ...
    [5  7   1];
```

And in the second month, I see this:

```
    edges = ...
    [5  7   2;
    5   11  2;];
```

And month by month, more edges are added until the complete data set show above is obtained.

**EDIT**

The third column is the moment identifier and using this article ([Filter Matrix by some column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341523/filter-matrix-by-some-column-value)
) I can loop through the matrix and obtain a filtered_edges to use in the graph() function.

**END EDIT**

The easy way would be to create different edges files and read them one by one, but is there a way to do this programmatically with Matlab?

Comment: Could you detail more the dataset that you are using ?

Comment: @EAA - Just added more details about how edges evolve over time.

Comment: Any reason my answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: @SteveHeim Respectfully, your solution equates to creating multiple figures the way I was expecting to avoid. I can simply create one **graph** for each period of time with varying edge files, but that was the challenge, how not to simply show figures one on top of the other.

Comment: @Iwall, no worries, I didn't understand what you're actually looking for. If I understand correctly, you want 1 figure, and over time new edges get added to the same figure? So for example, every 2 seconds, more data data gets added? In other words, you want an animated graph, yes?

Comment: @SteveHeim Yes, an animated graph is what I am looking for. Thank for saying it like that, it is a more clear explanation. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Okay, I changed my answer, does that work?

Comment: @SteveHeim Yes it does. I'll adapt the code to use with a graph. Thanks!

Comment: @Iwall if it works, feel free to accept the answer ; )

Comment: @SteveHeim as provided, it works. I am trying to adapt your code using the graph() function, plus trying to use the data as explained in the edited version of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [mathworks documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) for details. For your case, here you go:

```
data = rand(6,2);

figure
% You need to somehow fix your axes, so that they don't resize
axis tight manual
ax = gca;
ax.NextPlot = 'replaceChildren';


% Let's record this to file
v = VideoWriter('myAnimation.avi');
v.FrameRate = 10; % slow down the animation
open(v);

loops = size(data,1);
F(loops) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]); % Struct to hold frames

for i = 1:loops
    plot(data(1:i,1),data(1:i,2),'*'); % plot what you want in the new frame
    drawnow % clear and draw new frame
    frame = getframe;

    F(i) = frame; % if you want to animate locally you only need this
    pause(0.1); % this just slows down locally, can be removed and does NOT influence the saved video

    writeVideo(v,frame); % this is only if you want to save to file
end
close(v);
```